# declare CursorName cursor for ... VS declare @CursorName cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any difference other than syntax?

Comment: `declare @CursorName` will declare a variable. Which means it automatically gets closed and deallocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a variable name (see MS documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)).  See the `cursor_name` section where it is simply referred to as a variable name.  Naming of a variable has no consequences for its behaviour.

Comment: I was running some tests and I notice that the creation of a cursor variable will not add an entry to the result of sp_cursor_list.

Comment: I have posted another question on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248701/advantages-on-using-cursor-variable-in-sql-server-declare-cn-cursor