# Advantages on using cursor variable in SQL Server (declare @cn cursor)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, database-cursor

In T-SQL a cursor can be declared in two ways (that I know of):

1. `declare CursorName cursor for ...`
2. `declare @CursorName cursor`

I was running some tests and I notice that the creation of a cursor variable will not add an entry to the result of `sp_cursor_list`.

Is there any advantage/disadvantage on using the second approach from the point of view of performance, resource utilization, etc?

PS: *I am aware of potential cursor performance issues. I am not asking for a comparison on cursors vs set based. Or cursor vs `while` with temp/table variable.*

Comment: If performance is a consideration, you probably shouldn't be using cursors :)

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you **must** use a cursor, I would always try to use the `DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD` if I ever can. But your best performance optimization would really be to avoid cursors if ever possible.

Comment: I am aware of potential cursor performance issues, but that's not what my question is about. I am not asking for a comparison on cursors vs set based. Or cursor vs while with temp/table variable.

Comment: You can loop without a cursor.  I'd personally poke my own eyes out before I ever used a cursor in my code.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935336/sql-server-cursor-reference-syntax-etc/935367#935367 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967054/what-are-the-different-ways-to-replace-a-cursor/967130#967130  I've taken slow legacy cursor code that caused locks and block and just replaced the cursor with one of these SELECT loops and seen significant performance improvements.

Comment: I'd go with HLGEM's answer... your problem is that experience SQL Server types will avoid CURSORs and aren't familiar with the finer points such as this. Not that I'm saying they're for amateurs you understand :-)

Comment: when using second approach, cursor will be closed and de-allocated automatically when variable goes out of the scope, while in the first case you'd need to explicitly close and deallocate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I read the purpose of the cursor variable is to be able to use it as an output variable in stored proc, thus enabling you to send the data in the cursor to another controlling proc. I have not tried this so I don't know exactly how it would work, but that is what I get from reading Books Online. I would be surprised if there is any measurable performance difference and certainly not the the improvement you could get by not using a cursor in the first place. If you aren't planning to use it as an output variable, I'd suggest that staying with the more common cursor definiton might make the code easier to maintain.

That said, there are very, very few cases where a cursor is actually needed.

Comment: Having dealt with more than one SQL Server experiencing severe cursor leaks (i.e. cursor opens >> cursor closes), I slightly prefer cursor variables (or avoiding the use of cursors). Leaks are obviously due to bad code (missing close and deallocate statements), and fixing that requires a minor rewrite (for each cause of a leak). I don't strongly prefer cursor variables. I just consider them to be more "bad code defensive", simply because they have local scope.

Answer (score 7):

There is another advantage to using the `DECLARE @local_variable CURSOR` syntax that I just discovered.

The advantage occurs when one stored procedure calls another, and both procedures have cursors open at the same time.  If `DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR` is used to define the cursors, and both procedures use the same cursor_name, then you get

> Msg 16915: A cursor with the name 'cursor_name' already exists.

On the other hand, If `DECLARE @local_variable CURSOR` is used to define the cursors in the parent and child stored procedures, then `@local_variable` is local to each procedure and there is no conflict. For those who haven't used this method before, here is an example, using `@C` as the local variable:

```
DECLARE @C AS CURSOR;

SET @C = CURSOR FOR SELECT ...;

OPEN @C;

FETCH NEXT FROM @C INTO ...;
```

...

Comment: It is not really an advantage, as you can declare cursors as local, like this DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR LOCAL in each SP and then there will be no names clash.

Comment: Though if any error comes in the runtime the cursor with @ will be closed & deallocated automatically, where as regular cursor needs to be handled in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid cursers as much as possible (at least if you think about performance). Try to create a set based solution for your problem. They will usually be processed much faster then a cursor based solution.

Comment: While I agree, this isn't really addressing his question.

Comment: The use of a cursor does not preclude a set-based approach. You may have 1B rows, and cannot effectively do an operation for all rows simultaneously. In these operations, a loop is often the best approach, and you should use the looping mechanism that works best for your situation. SQL has `While` loops, and I tend to think of cursors as the equivalent of a `For` loop, since it will iterate for each element in the cursor. There is no inherent benefit of one over the other, and having the option is better than not.

Comment: I did mention you should think about the performance. Handling 1B records places a serious constrain on the memory and you will have an issue with the set based approach (unless its a real beefy server and a narrow table). I didn't say DONT use cursors but avoid as much as possible.